# Why is my *ngFor displaying two empty items

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a service with a getter that gets all my student data. If I add a student and use subscribe to indicate that my Student array changed it works but how will I implement this on a get method.

I am new with angular so any help would be great!!

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div *ngIf="students">
      <ul *ngFor="let student of students" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h3>{{ student.studentname }}</h3>
          <h3>{{ student.studentsurname }}</h3>
          <h3>{{ student.studentnumber }}</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';
import { Student } from '../student.model';

import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';
import { Student } from '../student.model';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-students',
  templateUrl: './all-students.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-students.component.css']
})
export class AllStudentsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) { }
  studentSub: Subscription;
  students: Student[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.students = this.studentService.getStudents();
    this.studentService.studentChanged.next(this.students)
    this.studentSub = this.studentService.studentChanged.subscribe(
      (students: Student[]) => {
        this.students = this.studentService.getStudents();
      }
    )
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from './student.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {

  private students: Student[] = [
    new Student('Bernhardt', 'du Toit', 17001847),
    new Student('Chane', 'van der Merwe', 17001848)
  ];

  studentChanged = new Subject<Student[]>()

  getStudent(index: number){
    return this.students[index];
  }

  getStudents(){
    return this.students.slice();
  }

  addStudent(student: Student){
    this.students.push(student);
    this.studentChanged.next(this.students.slice())
  }

  addStudents(students: Student[]){
    this.students.push(...students);
    this.studentChanged.next(this.students.slice())
  }
}
```

Attached is my html file, my ts file and my service.

Again any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What does your `student.model` look like?

Comment: export class Student {
  public stname: string;
  public stsurname: string;
  public stnumber: number;

  constructor(stname: string, stsurname: string, stnumber: number) {
    this.stname = stname;
    this.stsurname = stsurname;
    this.stnumber = stnumber;
  }
}

Comment: It seems you want put on the screen "student.studentname" but your data model define "student.stname" in this context "student.studentname" is undefined then nothing is displayed

Comment: It fixed it thank you Mathieu Berthellemy I was overthinking it so much I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the names to match those of the student class.

```
div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div *ngIf="students">
      <ul *ngFor="let student of students" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h3>{{ student.stname}}</h3>
          <h3>{{ student.stsurname }}</h3>
          <h3>{{ student.stnumber}}</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```